# How do you show a list of attendees in an Outlook 2013 calendar event?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, office365

A coworker recently enabled an extra view inside Outlook, so that when he opens up a meeting on his calendar he immediately sees a list of the people attending the meeting.

How do you enable this in Outlook 2013?

[image: An Outlook calendar event with a list of attendees shown]

(I know you can simply switch to the Scheduling Assistant view, but I want to see everything in a single view! First-world problems.)

Answer (score 25):

The answer is *not* in the Options window or even the messages pane. It was tucked away in the Views ribbon with some other options that are exclusive to the window.

[image: View ribbon, People Pane, set to Normal]

- It should be noted that **you need to enable the Outlook Social Connector 2013 add-on for this trick to work**. I had just disabled several extensions, but luckily I had kept this one.
- Once this is set, you can even enable the Reading Pane to have the meeting recipients, meeting notes, and calendar in the same Outlook window.

Answer (score 8):

If you click `propose new time`, you can see the other people.

You don't have to send the new proposed time.